# Create a list using values_list() in django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get the values of the objects saved in my database in a list and as integer, but the code I'm using is not working: if I try number[1:] I'm just gettin a blank variable in the html page and I keep getting errors telling me I'm still working with queryset and not list.

```
number = list(Week.objects.filter(user=request.user).values_list())
```

How Can I get a simple list using .values_list()?

**EDIT:** Added the model

```
class Week(models.Model):    
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserData, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file = models.OneToOneField(File, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    monday     = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    tuesday    = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    wednesday  = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    thursday   = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    friday     = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    saturday   = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    sunday     = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
```

Comment: `.values()` list will make use of *all* fields. It makes not much sense to concatenate all fields in a simple list, since that would remove the "structure". Do you want to fetch *one* field, if yes, which?

Comment: Can you provide the relevant model?

Comment: I edited the question with my model. I do need all the field values excepet the first one.

Comment: your `Week` also does not appear to have a relation to the `User`?

Comment: Fixed the edit with the right model with the user

Comment: and another issue might be that there can be *multiple* weeks for the same user. In that case what should happen?

Comment: That's really not a problem, I just need that information for specific file. What I need for my project is just to create a list with the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
number = list(Week.objects.values_list(
    'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursay', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday'
).get(user=request.user, file=some_file))
```

I think it is better to explicitly list the fields: if later additional fields will appear in the `Week` module, it eventually can result in a lot of trouble to ensure that these are not in the `number` list.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a lot with the selection of the field! My only problem is that when I try to render the list in html I get the values between () like with my previous code, this doesn't usually happen with my other list and I think is the reason why I am not able to use the values to create a graph with chart.js. Is there a way to get a normal list? I stil can't even use [ : ], so maybe something is wrong?

Comment: @PisaPonente: did you use `.get(..)` instead of `.filter(..)`?